# Convert ImmutableListMultimap to Map using Collectors.toMap

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I would like to convert a  `ImmutableListMultimap<String, Character> to Map<String, List<Character>>`. 
I used to do it in the non-stream way as follows

```
    void convertMultiMaptoList(ImmutableListMultimap<String, Character> reverseImmutableMultiMap) {
            Map<String, List<Character>> result = new TreeMap<>();
          for( Map.Entry<String, Character> entry: reverseImmutableMultiMap.entries()) {
              String key = entry.getKey();
              Character t = entry.getValue();
          result.computeIfAbsent(key, x-> new ArrayList<>()).add(t);
       }
       //reverseImmutableMultiMap.entries().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap)
}
```

I was wondering how to write the above same logic using java8 stream way (Collectors.toMap).

Please share your thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map<String, List<Character>> result = reverseImmutableMultiMap.entries().stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getKey, TreeMap::new, mapping(Entry::getValue, toList())));
```

The important detail is [mapping](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-). It will convert the collector (`toList`) so that it collects `List<Character>` instead of `List<Entry<String, Character>>`. According to the mapping function `Entry::getValue`

[groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) will group all entries by the `String` key

[toList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) will collect all values with same key to a list

Also, passing `TreeMap::new` as an argument to `groupingBy` will make sure you get this specific type of `Map` instead of the default `HashMap`

Comment: Thanks for the answer and detailed explanation.

Comment: Now my doubt is,  which is more readable? The stream version or non-stream version? For me the stream version looks more readable but more may be doing more work than the nonstream. Look like I have to do a performance measure.

Comment: Readability in this case depends on familiarity with stream based code. Once one is familiar with the syntax and avoids nested streams they tend to be more readable and less error prone. In your original code for example I got confused with this line `result.computeIfAbsent(key, x-> new ArrayList<>()).add(t)` for a couple of seconds.

Comment: Performance wise I wouldn't expect much difference especially for large collections. Once the small upfront cost for setting up stream, collector, mapper is spent, it's basically the same work in each iteration either way. But do measure if it's important in this case!

Answer (score 4):

Well there is already a `asMap` that you can use to make this easier:

```
    Builder<String, Character> builder = ImmutableListMultimap.builder();
    builder.put("12", 'c');
    builder.put("12", 'c');

    ImmutableListMultimap<String, Character> map = builder.build();

    Map<String, List<Character>> map2 = map.asMap()
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, e -> new ArrayList<>(e.getValue())));
```

If on the other hand you are OK with the return type of the `asMap` than it's a simple method call:

```
 ImmutableMap<String, Collection<Character>> asMap =  map.asMap();
```